# How to do model.solve() not show any message in python using pulp?

Tags: python, pulp

I'm doing a implementation using pulp in python in a code that runtime is very important.

```
#Initialize model
model = LpProblem('eUCB_Model', sense=LpMaximize)
#Define decision variables
y = LpVariable.dicts('tenant', [(i) for i in range(size)], lowBound=None, upBound=None, cat='Binary')
#Define model
model += lpSum([y[i]*th_hat[t][i] for i in range(size)])
#Define Constraints
model += lpSum([y[i]*R[t][i] for i in range(size)]) <= C
#solving the model
model.solve()
```

my problem is, every time that I call to solve the model using `model.solve()` the method print a lot of informations in the terminal like this:

```
Welcome to the CBC MILP Solver 
Version: 2.9.0 
Build Date: Feb 12 2015 

command line - /Users/henriquelima/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pulp/apis/../solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc /var/folders/_6/r2j2fp7n5mxd5_1w2sbs8rvw0000gn/T/514d0624e4d645ae8582e6fa5203bc54-pulp.mps max ratio None allow None threads None presolve on strong None gomory on knapsack on probing on branch printingOptions all solution /var/folders/_6/r2j2fp7n5mxd5_1w2sbs8rvw0000gn/T/514d0624e4d645ae8582e6fa5203bc54-pulp.sol (default strategy 1)
At line 2 NAME          MODEL
At line 3 ROWS
At line 6 COLUMNS
At line 19 RHS
At line 21 BOUNDS
At line 25 ENDATA
Problem MODEL has 1 rows, 3 columns and 3 elements
Coin0008I MODEL read with 0 errors
String of None is illegal for double parameter ratioGap value remains 0
String of None is illegal for double parameter allowableGap value remains 0
String of None is illegal for integer parameter threads value remains 0
String of None is illegal for integer parameter strongBranching value remains 5
Option for gomoryCuts changed from ifmove to on
Option for knapsackCuts changed from ifmove to on
Continuous objective value is 2.03584 - 0.00 seconds
Cgl0004I processed model has 0 rows, 0 columns (0 integer (0 of which binary)) and 0 elements
Cbc3007W No integer variables - nothing to do
Cuts at root node changed objective from -2.03584 to -1.79769e+308
Probing was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Gomory was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Knapsack was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
Clique was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
MixedIntegerRounding2 was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
FlowCover was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
TwoMirCuts was tried 0 times and created 0 cuts of which 0 were active after adding rounds of cuts (0.000 seconds)
```

I want to run this method with no one type of information printed in my terminal, this can reduce considerable the time of execution of the program. Do you know how to do this?

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think showing the log is the performance issue. Anyways, as the documentation shows:
https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/technical/solvers.html#pulp.apis.PULP_CBC_CMD

You can just pass `msg=False` as argument by doing:

```py
model.solve(PULP_CBC_CMD(msg=False))
```

Comment: I have to run this code several time for instances very much longs, and this can affect the results. Your contribution was very important. thank you very much =)

Comment: When I add this I get the following error message: `pulp.apis.core.PulpSolverError: PULP_CBC_CMD: Not Available (check permissions on /Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/envs/pulp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pulp/solverdir/cbc/osx/64/cbc`